# How to prevent touch events on pseudo element in React app?

Tags: ios, reactjs, event-handling, pseudo-element, touch-event

I have pseudo element what covers a large part of the page. I want it to close a menu after click or tap, so I used `onClick={this.handleClick}`  on the parent.

Everything works fine except iPhones :
`onTouch` it works like click - the menu is closing,
`onTouchMove`, `onTouchEnd`, `onTouchStart` it starts to scroll content under the menu (pseudo-element).

I want to prevent this scrolling content behind the menu. How to eliminate this touch event bubbling?

On Android, it works just fine.

```
&::after {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 50px;
    min-height: calc(100% - 25px);
    content: $default-content;
}
```